# How to post to a facebook users wall using the php api with the access token and curl?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
 if (function_exists('curl_init')) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "access_token=$facebook_access_token&message=testing api.");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

where $facebook_access_token is a variable containing the access token.

Am I doing something wrong? I have to use the php api and I do not explicitly know the users facebook page url, only the access token.

Thanks.

Comment: Done it. I used the facebook api object instead - easier than using curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more option to cURL:

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER : false

```
if (function_exists('curl_init')) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "access_token=$facebook_access_token&message=testing api.");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```